# Email wizzard in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I need in custom module add button Send on Email as in "Purchase" or "Sale".

```xml
<button string="Send on email" class="oe_highlight" type="object" name="send_on_email" />
```

```py
@api.multi
def send_on_email(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    ir_model_data = self.env['ir.model.data']

    ??????
```

How generate and add file to attachment? On this form I have print button for that model.

Print get on this:

```xml
<report 
    id="print_my_qweb"
    model="my.model"
    string="Export to PDF"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    name="my.model.report_single"
    file="my.model.report_single"
/>
```